# How to create and assign API Key to a created stage-API using serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I want to create a secure APIG using serverless, in my current "***s-fuction.json***" I've already have:

```
"apiKeyRequired": true,
```

And in my "***s-resources-cf.json***" I already have:

```
"AWSApiKey": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey",
  "Properties" : {
    "Description" : "ApiKey for secure the connections to the xxx API",
    "Enabled" : true
  }
}
```

It correctly creates all, a Lambda, an APIG for that lambda (including CORS) and the API Key, but I need to manually "assign" the key to the generated APIG-Stage, do you have any ideas on how could I do this automatically using serverless?

I've read the AWS documentation about the feature I want (and It seems it is possible) from here: [AWS CloudFormation API Key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-apikey.html)

The documentation shows that it can be done by:

```
"ApiKey": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey",
  "DependsOn": ["TestAPIDeployment", "Test"],
  "Properties": {
    "Name": "TestApiKey",
    "Description": "CloudFormation API Key V1",
    "Enabled": "true",
    "StageKeys": [{
      "RestApiId": { "Ref": "RestApi" },
      "StageName": "Test"
    }]
  }
}
```

But I don't know how add a reference to the APIG automatically created by serverless and how to wait for that APIG is created.

Comment: Some additional information after researching this: Serverless 0.5 creates cloudformation stack before the Lambda function and the API gateway API. Thus it seems very hard (read: impossible) to know the RestApiId in advance. The api key needs to be created after the API exists. Serverless does not use Cloudformation for deploying APIs or Lambdas so these cannot be used as dependencies or references. After the Serverless deploy, the api key can be created with Cloudformation by providing the name, stage and api id as parameters. A proper solution would be nice.

Comment: This question refers to an outdated and discontinued version of the Serverless framework. In the latest version, API keys can easily be created, see: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#setting-api-keys-for-your-rest-api

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a list of API keys to be used by your service Rest API by adding an apiKeys array property to the provider object in serverless.yml. You'll also need to explicitly specify which endpoints are private and require one of the api keys to be included in the request by adding a private boolean property to the http event object you want to set as private. API Keys are created globally, so if you want to deploy your service to different stages make sure your API key contains a stage variable as defined below. When using API keys, you can optionally define usage plan quota and throttle, using usagePlan object.

Here's an example configuration for setting API keys for your service Rest API:

```
service: my-service
provider:
  name: aws
  apiKeys:
    - myFirstKey
    - ${opt:stage}-myFirstKey
    - ${env:MY_API_KEY} # you can hide it in a serverless variable
  usagePlan:
    quota:
      limit: 5000
      offset: 2
      period: MONTH
    throttle:
      burstLimit: 200
      rateLimit: 100
functions:
  hello:
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/create
          method: get
          private: true
```

For more info read the following doc:
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway